# Matlab Create 2d color graph from and interpolate 3d array

Tags: matlab, graph, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have a matrix that stores x, y and z values as so:

```
{x1, y1, z1},
{x2, y2, z2},
{x3, y3, z3},
etc...
```

I need to interpolate the data, and plot in on a 2d graph, with color representing the z value. ([example](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/Sfgrayplot.png))

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `griddata` might help you to interpolate:

```
x = vector(:,1);
y = vector(:,2);
z = vector(:,3);

% Settings
xres = 800; % Resolution, the higher, the smoother
yres = 800;         
cm = 'default'; % Colormap

% Axes Limits
xmin = min(x); 
ymin = min(y);
xmax = max(x); 
ymax = max(y); 
xi = linspace(xmin, xmax, xres);
yi = linspace(ymin, ymax, yres);

% Figure
myfig = figure('Position', [200 200 800 600]);

rotate3d off
[XI, YI] = meshgrid(xi, yi);
ZI = griddata(x, y, z, XI, YI, 'cubic');
mesh(XI,YI,ZI);
```

than you just need to change the view of it to only display a certain `plane` for a fixed value of `z`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Alexandrew [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9196128/163080) you can use newer and faster [TriScatteredInterp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/triscatteredinterp.html) class instead of GRIDDATA. For your exampe you can use 2D IMAGESC instead of 3D MESH.

```
%# insert the code from @Alexandrew answer to generate meshgrid
[XI, YI] = meshgrid(xi, yi);
TSI = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,z);
ZI = TSI(XI,YI);
imagesc(ZI)
colorbar
```

If your input matrix is a cell array, you can convert it to a numeric matrix with `a = cell2mat(a);`